# Vue: Emitter isn't working in child when using button click

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

My emit call is not getting called on my button click.  I tried to run a debugger and step through it and it gets triggered but looks like it steps right through and skips it.  I'm not sure what the issue is or why it's skipping.

**Parent**

```html
<step-review @emitgetappdata="getAppData"></step-review>
```

```js
getAppData: function(data=null) {
  debugger
}
```

**Step Review**

```html
<button @click="this.clickedButton()">Test</button>
```

```js
clickedButton: function() {
  console.log("reached here");
  let data = {
    text: "Foo",
  }
  this.$emit('emitgetappdata', data);
}
```

Comment: FYI, you can omit the `this.` prefix in `@click="this.clickedButton()"`

Comment: Could you please expand a bit more on _"looks like it steps right through and skips it"_. What does that mean? Are there any other statements in your `getAppData` method? What do you expect to see vs what you actually see?

Comment: Works fine over here ~ https://jsfiddle.net/4nhgtu8e/

Comment: @Phil What i mean "skips through it" is that it does take my to that function.  I press the down arrow to go line by line in the debugger and it goes right through it.  I have a console log and a debugger in `getAppData` function so I'm expecting to see that.  I just tried replacing the emitter with `this.$parent.getAppData()` and that worked so I'm not sure what the issue is with my emitter

Comment: @raulInsto do you using vue-cli, or vue.js from CDN? Please reproduce it on codesandbox.io and ill try to help resolve your issue

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `this` on view

```html
<button @click="clickedButton()">Test</button>
```

```js
clickedButton() {
  console.log("reached here");
  let data = {
    text: "Foo",
  }
  this.$emit('emitgetappdata', data);
}
```

and your component code to this a bit more clean.

```
<step-review @emitgetappdata="getAppData"></step-review> 

getAppData(data=null) {
  debugger
}
```

Edited after reading some docs :
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Data-and-Methods

Comment: `this.$emit` exists.  When I use the debugger right before calling the emit, I type in `this.$emit` and get a function back.

Comment: @raulInsto reproduce it on codesandbox then I'll help

Comment: @Phil nope if youre on vue SFC, take a look here https://codesandbox.io/s/thethisthing-x22iw